# On complementary factors for the Riemann's Zeta function for $\Re s>1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, mobius-function

For $\Re s>1$, I define the following functions $I(s)$ and $J(s)$, 
$$I(s)=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\mu(n)e^{-n^2\pi x}x^{s/2}\frac{dx}{x},$$ where $\mu(n)$ is the Möbius function, and the well known integral $$J(s)=\int_1^\infty\psi(x)\left(x^{-s/2}-x^{(1-s)/2}\right)\frac{dx}{x},$$ where $\psi(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^2\pi x}$.

> **Question.** I've deduced the following claims i) and ii) involving the Riemann's Zeta function, and I would like to know rigurous proofs of one of those (isn't required a proof of both statements, but I would like to know if both are correct):
>
> i) for $\Re s>1$ $$\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}\left(J(s)-\frac{1}{s(1-s)}\right)=I(s)\zeta(s),$$
>
> and ii) also for $\Re s>1$,
>   $$(s(1-s)J(s)-1)\left[\frac{I'(s)}{I(s)}+2\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}\right]=s(1-s)J'(s)+\frac{1-2s}{s(1-s)}.$$ **Thank you for reading my question.**

As remark I say that then $I(s)$ and $J(s)$ are **complementary factors** of the Riemann Zeta function $\zeta(s)$ for $\Re s>1$, just as a terminology.

Comment: In a next post I present different equations involging also a complementary factor based in the Liouville function.

Comment: It is easy to show that $I(s) = \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2) \frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$. For showing $J(s) =  \pi^{-s/2} \Gamma(s/2)  \zeta(s)-\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}s$ you'll need the Poisson summation formula, [see the second part of this post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/242907/xi-function-on-critical-strip-mellin-transform/242959#242959). Anything else ?

Comment: You are incredible, your expression for $I(s)$ is right but now I don't know how get $J(s)$ using Poisson summation formula. You are welcome if you want add remarks to get $J(s)$ or ii). Many thanks @user1952009

Comment: The steps I wrote in the linked question are in every book/course on $\zeta(s)$ (it is the standard proof of the functional equation, that works not only for $\zeta(s)$ but also for many other $L$-functions). All you need is a Fourier series, or the Fourier transform with the Poisson summation formula.

Comment: @Agno I believe that in the past I've read some of your posts in Math Overflow and then I've copied some of such techniques. This afternoon I was revising some posts in MO and I see one more time these posts and I've concluded that without intention I could have copied such ideas in my questions. Regards.

Comment: [The other proof is](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Relation_fonctionnelle) with the Fourier series $x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}=  - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{\pi n}$ and $\zeta(s) = -s \int_0^\infty (x - \lfloor x \rfloor - \frac{1}{2}) x^{-s-1}dx$ for $Re(s) \in (-1,0)$.

Comment: Thus $$(1-2^{s})\zeta(s) = s \int_0^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1}\frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{\pi n} x^{-s-1}dx = s  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin(2\pi n x)}{\pi n} x^{-s-1}dx $$ $$ =s  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} n^{1-s}\int_0^\infty\sin(2\pi  x) x^{-s-1}dx = s(1-2^s)\zeta(1-s)\int_0^\infty\sin(2\pi  x) x^{-s-1}dx$$

Comment: Now please, work on this (the functonial equation) prove everything in detail (you'll need many analysis theorems), and don't ask any other question on $\zeta(s)$ until everything is clear

Comment: Many thaks for your efforts @user1952009 Now  I read it.